# Is there any features in swagger 2.0 where I can put more than one type of request

Tags: api, swagger, documentation

I have different types of payload which i need to post it as a request in swagger .
But i am not sure of i put all the payload at once.

Please help me out 
I am blocked.

If the question is unclear, please let me know

Comment: Can you provide examples of those different types of payload? I.e. how do they differ?

Comment: Hey Helen, all payloads are in xml format but they differ a lot in elements and attributes and its a very lengthy payload.    Helen can i please get your gmail id ? @Helen

Comment: @Helen please send me your mail id